# Matlab stop it from auto adjusting plot3 zoom while rotating

Tags: matlab

When panning the camera, the zoom level is auto adjusted causing the data to shift around. This is disorienting and I'd like to disable it. The size of my data should stay the same even if I'm rotating around.

[image]

I'm using appdesigner and my "Add" button loads a dataset from an SQL file. This code is in my button callback:

```
plot3(app.UIAxes, data,"x","y", "z", Color="green")
plot3(app.UIAxes, dataSensor,"x","y","z", Color="blue")

hold(app.UIAxes, "on")
zoom(app.UIAxes, "on")

axis(app.UIAxes,'vis3d')

props = {'CameraViewAngle','DataAspectRatio','PlotBoxAspectRatio'};
set(app.UIAxes,props,get(app.UIAxes,props));

setAxes3DPanAndZoomStyle(zoom(app.UIAxes),app.UIAxes,'camera')

app.UIAxes.XLimMode = 'manual'
app.UIAxes.YLimMode = 'manual'
app.UIAxes.ZLimMode = 'manual'
app.UIAxes.PlotBoxAspectRatioMode = "manual"
app.UIAxes.PlotBoxAspectRatio = [1 1 1]
app.UIAxes.DataAspectRatioMode = "manual"
app.UIAxes.DataAspectRatio = [1 1 1]
app.UIAxes.CameraViewAngle = 0
app.UIAxes.CameraViewAngleMode = "manual"
```

A mixture of things I've read in various forums that seemingly are supposed to turn off this behavior but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

Misunderstood CameraViewAngle and after setting it to 15 fixed my issues.

I guess the problem was it was auto calculating the FOV angle since it was set to 0.